# "get up a level" or "get up by a level"?

Tags: grammar

Tell me please which sentence is correct and why.

> To get your English skills up a level, you need to use it more.
>
> To get your English skills up **by** a level, you need to use it more.

I am confused because I heard English native speakers say similar sentences without *by*, but I thought that if something increases we need to use *by*. For example:

> The ocean level has increased by a few inches in the last decades.

Comment: First, we don't normally have English levels. So, either version sounds odd. However, the use of the preposition is optional. (Both are acceptable; the choice is yours.)

Comment: How would you rephrase the sentence?

Comment: There are *many* different ways of phrasing it. Here's one: *To improve your English, keep on using it.*

Comment: @JasonBassford As a sentence, I agree that the use of the word "by" is optional but as a saying, I believe  "up a level" is more common. The saying doesn't sound odd to me. Perhaps it is a regional thing. (I am from Southern England)

Comment: @RedPython The only context where *up* ***a level*** sounds natural is in games, where the character you play can *level up*. If applied to real life in general, it sound like the speaker is deliberately making this association or just doesn't speak English natively.

Comment: @JasonBassford Like I said, it sounds fine to me.